# Al enviar formulario por Ajax me recarga la pagina

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

mi problema es que tengo una pagina con varios `form` a los cuales pretendo hacerle peticiones ajax para que no recargue la pagina, pero me la recarga y no se cual es el motivo, he invetigado y he tratado de varias formas, pero ninguna me resulta, este es mi codigo:

```js
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    // function enviar(){

      $('#btn_predio').submit(function(event) {
        alert('entro a la funcion');
        event.preventDefault();  
        // var url = //$(this).attr('action');  
        var datos = $(this).serialize();
      var url = "../../controller/radication_controller.php";                                      

      $.ajax({   
         cache: false,                     
         type: "POST",                 
         url: url,                    
         data: datos,
         success: function(data)            
         {
           $('#btn_predio').reset();
            alert(data);
         }
       });
      // return false;
      });
    // }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="frPredio" id="frPredio"  method="post">
  <div class="col-lg-12 form-group"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 input-group">
    <div class="col-lg-6 input-group">
      <label for="dirActual" class="col-form-label col-lg-5">Dirección (Actual)</label>
      <input type="text" name="dirActual" class="form-control col-lg-7">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 input-group">
      <label for="BarrioActual" class="col-form-label col-lg-5">Barrio  (Actual)</label>
      <input type="text" name="BarrioActual" class="form-control col-lg-7">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-lg-12 input-group" >
    <div class="col-lg-5"></div>
    <button type="button" name="btn_predio" id="btn_predio" value="predio" class=" btn btn-danger agregar col-lg-2" >
      <span class="fa fa-floppy-o"></span> Guardar 
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

en el success del ajax tengo un alert que se supone debe detener el flujo de jecucion, pero lo ignora y me recarga la pagina.

he intentado varias cosas, pero nada funciona. agradezco la ayuda que me brinden

Comment: Prueba en lugar de colocar un button para enviar el formulario, colocar un input type submit, o sino en tu JS, en donde seleccionas btn_predio, pon el id del form para que hagas el event.preventDefault()

Comment: nada bro, ahora nisiquiera la recarga y las alertas tampoco las muestra

Comment: Intentastes quitar el atributo `method` del formulario?

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav tambien y nada....

Comment: Te estoy elaborando una respuesta que seguro te funcionara, solo modificare un poco el js y cualquier cosa o duda me comentas en esa respuesta

Comment: ok, esperare...

Comment: Esta recomendación me sirvió para el mismo problema, específicamente el puesto en negrilla:
Prueba en lugar de colocar un button para enviar el formulario, colocar un input type submit, o sino en tu JS, en donde seleccionas btn_predio, pon el id del form para que hagas el **event.preventDefault()** – darioxlz el 25 sep. 18 a las 2:07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifique tu código JS un poco nada mas:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

  $('#btn_predio').on("click", (e) =>  {
    enviar();      
  });

});

const enviar = () => {
  alert("Entro en la función enviar");
  const datos = $("#frPredio").serialize();

  $.ajax({   
    cache: false,                     
    type: "POST",                 
    url: "../../controller/radication_controller.php",                    
    data: datos,
    error: function(request, status, error)
    {
      alert("ocurrio un error "+request.responseText)
      console.log(error)
    },
    success: function(data)            
    {
      alert("Hizo el success");
      console.log(data);
    }
  });

}
```

Lo primero que hice fue separar la función **enviar** y llamará desde un evento **click** del botón **#btn_predio**. Tambien agrege un handler del error por si te esta dando un error en el ajax.

Espero te funcione, Saludos.

Comment: Broder, me muetra la alerta del suces, pero cuando le doy aceptar de igual forma me recarga la pagina

Comment: hay mas de un botón con ese mismo id?

Comment: Listo master, solo cambie el type del boton y funciono, gracias bro... me salvo, aunque quede sin entender el porque, comparo los js y en teoria hacen lo mismo, solo cambia la sintaxis, pero si funciona... gracias bro

Comment: Si hacen lo mismo pero como es un ajax evito el hacerle un submit para evitar esos errores, a veces es la version dle jquery otras que redunda el button con el submit, que bueno que solventastes saludos

Answer (score 0):

En este código probaste con

```
$('#btn_predio').on("click", (e) =>  {
    e.preventDefault(); // -> Este codigo ?????
    enviar();      
});
```

Comment: puedes explicar tu respuesta por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba algo como esto, sin el submit:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
                                            $('#boton_submit').click(function() {                     



                                      var url = "controladores/controladora.php";
                                                $.ajax({
                                                    type: "POST",
                                                    url: url,
                                                    data: $("#id_formulario").serialize(),
                                                    success: function(data)
                                                    {
                                                        a = data;

                                                        $('#id_formulario')[0].reset();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            });
```